How to ensure sns.heatmap has fixed cell sizes?
I have a function to plot heatmaps of the gene expression. I want to ensure that the size of the cells in the heatmap is always the same, regardless of the length of the genes to plot. To do this, I tried making the figure size variable such that it adjusts based on the length of the genes heatmap_height = len(filtered_genes_list) * 0.2. However, this seems to work when the gene list is of length < 4, but after that there is a super weird scaling going on that I cannot seem to figure out.
I've checked this page: Seaborn clustermap fixed cell size, but cannot seem to figure out how to apply this for my own heatmap.
Can anyone help me to figure out how I can make sure the size of the cells in the heatmap are always the same height, regardless of how long the genes list is? I'd like my figures to be consistent across different lengths of gene sets.
Kind Regards
